# PL/SQL: What return value for a function with exception

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Normaly my function return the value for the sallary of a employee with the empno as input to the function. If no employee with the given number exists I want to throw an exception who writes to the screen ("No employee with this employee number found!"). The problem is that then theres no number as return value, so how can I solve this in Oracle PL/SQL?

Comment: What have you tried? The key is to have an exception handler, like when no_data_found then write_to_the_screen. Good luck.

Comment: EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee not found!');
 RETURN sal_output;

this is how my exception handler looks like - btw: atm it writes nothing to the screen

Comment: In that case, search SO for `set serveroutput`. your issue has been asked and answered one jillion times. Also, your original question is utterly incomplete and misleading on what your actual issue is.

Answer (score 3):

If an exception is thrown, their is no return value. An exception is raised and the call stack ends there.

You can most certainly use no_data_found in a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function get_employees (pID in varchar2) return Number 
As
salary Number;
begin

begin
select e.salary into salary from employees e where employee_id=pID;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
salary := -1;
END;

return salary;

end get_employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function get_employees (id in varchar2) return varchar2 is

   sal employees.salary%type;

begin

   select salary  into sal from employees where employee_id=id;

   return sal;

EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001, 'Custom NO_DATA_FOUND');    
end get_employees;
```

you cannot use NO_DATA_FOUND in a function because it will give a predefined exception for null return .

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following example help to resolve the issue of returning....

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON ;

    /

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_CHK
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS   
        V_CHK NUMBER :=1;
    BEGIN
        FOR I IN 1..100
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I);
            IF(I>=4) THEN
                --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BREAK');
                V_CHK:=0;
                --V_CHK:=0/0;
                exit;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN V_CHK;
      
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    V_CHK:=1000;  


    RETURN V_CHK;
    END;


    /


    SELECT FN_CHK
    FROM DUAL;
```